# Solaris x86 downgrade NVIDIA driver

Tags: solaris, nvidia-graphics-card, x86

I had to reinstall Solaris/x86 11 and in the process upgraded to version 11.3 from 11.1 on the same machine.  The NVIDIA drivers were also updated, but there is a message during X startup that the latest driver does not support the NVIDIA card I have, and that I need to install the 340.xx legacy driver.

I've downloaded the necessary .run file from NVIDIA, and when run as root with 'sh', it responds,

```
pkgrm: ERROR: unable to change current working directory to /var/sadm/pkg/NVDAgraphics/install

Removal of  failed (internal error).
No changes were made to the system.
ERROR: Cannot uninstall the already installed package NVDAgraphics
```

I've also tried to delete manually using pkgrm with the same results. Further, when I go to /var/sadm/pkg/NVDAgraphics, there is no "install" file, only "pkginfo".   Finally, the graphical Package Manager will not remove the NVDAgraphics either - the Remove option is grayed out.

Any suggestions as to what  I need to do next?  Thanks!

Comment: Update: Got "Remove" to activate (no longer grayed out) in Package Manager by checking the checkbox for the package. Before, I had simply highlighted it, then right mouse-clicked.  But, when I clicked "Remove", I got, "This is a Live Image. The install operation can't be performed."

Comment: What is the format of the package you want to install?  Old-style SVR (Solaris 10), or new-style IPS (Solaris 11)?  The easiest thing to do may be to expand the package and just copy over the driver and config files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, except the fact that I installed the system from scratch, with the Nvidia driver package that didn't want to uninstall.

After some research, I found the solution on this site : https://blogs.oracle.com/alanc/entry/solaris_11_3_beta_changes under the section "NVIDIA graphics driver packages" that explained how to switch to the R340 Legacy package by using this command :

`# pkg install --reject driver/graphics/nvidia driver/graphics/nvidiaR340`

It worked for me.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

With the system's reply (reported in the comment above) about "Live image", I think I can answer my own question.  I found this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/E21798/compareinstall.html#scrolltoc)  stating that a Live Image does not install packages from a repository, so it seems the packages are integral to the live build I installed.

To get the other functionality, one must choose AI (Automated Installer) media, but this is a multistep process where you create a custom .iso from the AI.

I've used live installs for Linux and didn't have these restrictions to upgrade/ downgrade included packages, but hey, UNG (Unix's Not Gnu).  Live and learn.

Answer (score 0):

I have Geforce GTX 1070 Ti. Rhe Nvidia driver for Solaris requires Solaris to be installed as legacy BIOS. If you have installed Solaris using UEFI, then it is impossible to install the Nvidia driver. The disk is either UEFI (i.e. GPT formatted) or it is legacy BIOS (i.e. MBR formatted). It can not be both, this means you can not dual install Win10 (which is UEFI) and Solaris using BIOS.